# OrientDB: How can I filter Edge by node in orientdb

Tags: orientdb

How can I filter the edges by node condition? Below is my query, I would like to further filter the path by ending node with id 222

> SELECT $path as path FROM (
>       TRAVERSE bothE(),bothV() FROM (select * from Node where  (id in ['111']))
>       WHILE $depth <= 6 )
>   where @rid in (select @rid from Node where (id in ['222']))

However, the query only returns one path. But I know, there are several paths.

Comment: Which OrientDB version are you using?

Comment: I'm using OrientDb 2.2.32

Comment: The current solution is using java API filter the result by the last vertex.However, this solution is too slow, it takes 10mins for this query.

Comment: Hi, could you post an example of your structure? Thx